# .htaccess file has no values for time_mon, time_year apache vars

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, environment

I'm trying to do some apache URL rewriting via .htaccess. I want to rewrite based on time and date. We want certain images to be displayed during the month of june, and other images displayed after june.

So in my .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} = 05
RewriteRule ^Google_LP.png /img/img/ids/bg.png
```

But I get 500 errors on the site now, so there must be an error here. When I displayed my apache ENV vars via phpinfo(), I see there is no value for any of the apache time variables -- TIME_MON, TIME_YEAR, TIME_MIN, etc, don't exist. I do see a REQUEST_TIME, but it's a number of seconds since the epoch.

Would there be a reason there is nothing in TIME_MON? Is it an apache configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no white space allowed between `=` and `05`. Try

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} =05
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. The other item is that the months actually do get their normal numbers. January is not month 00, but month 01. Hence I was stuck on thinking June would be 05, but it's actually month 06.